# Is this Article misleading about the diffraction part?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, diffraction

The following article states that because of the diffraction, the egg is visible, I don't think that's correct, because diffraction occurs at every edge that light passes but it will just slightly increase the field of view, not the whole egg.

https://www.jordanthrilla.com/post/how-does-the-mirror-know-an-object-is-there-scientific-explanation-behind-viral-egg-tiktok-video/

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: The claim that it's diffraction is incorrect, but the schematic image in the article is correct - however, that's just ordinary reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the video (since there is no link), but if the last two images in the article are representative at all, this has nothing to do with diffraction, just geometry. Of course a paper you put between an object and a mirror will not in general prevent the object from being seen in the mirror from all angles.

As a rule you should probably be skeptical of physics claims you find in many (if not most) popular science sources, let alone on a website on "urban stories, hip-hop news, sports gossip, viral conspiracy theories...".

Comment: Yeah, the viral tiktok video simply isn't viral enough. The important part of the mirror in the egg-mirror-eye geometry is the part that satisfies ``angle of incidence = angle of reflection", and that part is just not being covered by the paper. The whole thing is just a scam for the scientifically illiterate. Good on Akash to have caught it.